# "Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of type 'channel.rician'" error on MATLAB, how to fix it?

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

When i run the following code, i have an error, what is the problem? and how can i fix it? Here is the code:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
% basic inputs =============================
fc=2e9;     % Hz  Carrier frequency
F=16;        % sampling rate: fraction of wave length
V=10;        %  m/s MS1 speed 
NFFT=128;    % Number of points in FFT
Nsamples=100; % Number of samples
% geometry inputs ===========================
dBS=1000;     % distance of BS to origin
alpha = 180;   % degree. Angle of BS-MS with MS route 
% inidirect gemeotric parameters ================
BSx=dBS*cosd(alpha);  % loc of BS x-coord
BSy=dBS*sind(alpha);  % loc of BS y-coord
% indirect parameters ===========================
c=3e8;
lambdac=c/fc;        % m wavelength
Dx=lambdac/F;      % m sampling spacing
ts=Dx/V;                % s time sampling interval
fs=1/ts;                   % Hz sampling frequency
kc=2*pi/lambdac;   % propagation constant
timeaxis=ts.*[0:Nsamples];     % s  elapsed time axis
disaxis=Dx.*[0:Nsamples];      % n  traveled distance axis 
MSx=V.*timeaxis;    % MS route sampling points
% radio path length============================== 
distBSMS=sqrt((BSx-MSx).^2+(BSy).^2);
% complex envelope: amplitude and phase ===============
rx=1*exp(-1j*kc.*distBSMS)-exp(-1j*2*pi/(c./5e9).*distBSMS);
c1 = ricianchan;
r=c1.*rx;
% complex envelope spectrum   ======================
spectrumr=fftshift((abs(fft(r,NFFT))).^2);
freqaxis=[0:NFFT-1]*fs/NFFT-fs/2;
% Plots =====================================
figure,plot(timeaxis,abs(r))
xlabel('Time (s)') ;
```

And this is the error:

```
Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of type 'channel.rician'
```

What is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises on this line:

```
r=c1.*rx;
```

Here, `rx` is a (complex) vector, while `c1` has a type of `channel.rician`, which I'm not familiar with. You define `c1` on the previous line:

```
c1 = ricianchan;
```

What is this supposed to give you? If you simply type `c1` in the command window, you can see which fields of `c1` is available:

```
>> c1

c1 =

               ChannelType: 'Rician'
         InputSamplePeriod: 1
           DopplerSpectrum: [1x1 doppler.jakes]
           MaxDopplerShift: 0
                PathDelays: 0
             AvgPathGaindB: 0
                   KFactor: 1
    DirectPathDopplerShift: 0
       DirectPathInitPhase: 0
        NormalizePathGains: 1
              StoreHistory: 0
            StorePathGains: 0
                 PathGains: 1.0657 + 0.8151i
        ChannelFilterDelay: 0
      ResetBeforeFiltering: 1
       NumSamplesProcessed: 0c1 =

               ChannelType: 'Rician'
         InputSamplePeriod: 1
           DopplerSpectrum: [1x1 doppler.jakes]
                PathDelays: 0
             AvgPathGaindB: 0
                   KFactor: 1
    DirectPathDopplerShift: 0
       DirectPathInitPhase: 0
        NormalizePathGains: 1
              StoreHistory: 0
            StorePathGains: 0
                 PathGains: 1.0657 + 0.8151i
        ChannelFilterDelay: 0
      ResetBeforeFiltering: 1
       NumSamplesProcessed: 0MaxDopplerShift: 0
                PathDelays: 0
             AvgPathGaindB: 0
                   KFactor: 1
    DirectPathDopplerShift: 0
       DirectPathInitPhase: 0
        NormalizePathGains: 1
              StoreHistory: 0
            StorePathGains: 0
                 PathGains: 1.0657 + 0.8151i
        ChannelFilterDelay: 0
      ResetBeforeFiltering: 1
       NumSamplesProcessed: 0
```

Let's say that what you really want is the complex number `PathGains`, then replace the erroneous line with

```
r=c1.PathGains.*rx;
```